# How to find that jscrol knob hit the bottom corner?

Tags: java, jscrollbar

I want to make an event when the jscroll knob hit the bottom corner in `VerticalScrollBar`. How to do it?

Comment: My first port of call would be the JavaDocs for [`JScrollBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

public class JScrollBarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr=new JFrame();

        JLabel l=new JLabel("test");
        l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(l);
        fr.add(scroll);
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                JScrollBar sc=scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
                System.out.println(sc.getVisibleAmount());
                System.out.println(sc.getMaximum());
                System.out.println(sc.getValue());
                System.out.println("------");
                if (sc.getVisibleAmount()+sc.getValue()==sc.getMaximum()) {
                    System.out.println("Bottom event");
                }
            }
        });

        fr.setSize(100, 100);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just simple way to achieve space in a JScrollPane:-) Of course I know that ppixel perfect layout is not good. Suppose I'm goint to write canvas for paint app with background image.